# store multiple dataframe.info to array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine the information from dataframe.info from a couple of dataframes into one table to be exported.

I think the best way to do this is to pull df1.info into an array and then do some cutting so only the column and count info remains.

Here is roughly what I want to do in code:

```
import pandas as pd
files=["file1", "file2"]
for filename in files:
    df= pd.read_csv(filename)
    info=df.info()
    *convert info to info[]*
    *cut first 3 rows and last 2 rows*
    output=output.extend(info)
```

Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: df.info() does not return any object, it just prints it out. Why don't you just get `count()` for every column, then type of every column and number of non-null values? Is this what you are really after?

Answer (score 0):

Since `df.info()` prints to `stdout`, you can harvest it by temporally redirecting IO to a `StringIO` object:

```
import contextlib
import io

def get_info_middle(df):
    fobj = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(fobj) as stdout:
        df.info()
    fobj.seek(0)
    return '\n'.join(fobj.read().splitlines()[3:-2])
```

#### Example

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

In [2]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    3 non-null int64
b    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 128.0 bytes

In [3]: print(get_info_middle(df))
a    3 non-null int64
b    3 non-null int64
```